# Why does it seem that the widgets share the same canvas in Kivy?

Tags: kivy

The Kivy documentation specifies that ["each widget in Kivy already have by default their Canvas"](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Canvas). However, in practice, it seems that the widgets hold a reference to a shared canvas of the whole window instead of having one just for themselves.

This becomes more clear when I use the `context_instrucions` of `Rotate`, `Translate` or `Scale`. If I `Rotate` inside a particular `Widget`, it will affect subsequent widgets. Everything seems to have rotated. I have to un-`Rotate` the canvas before drawing anything else. Moreover, it doesn't really matter if it is in the rotated canvas or in the next one. The same happens with the instruction `Color`.

The only way to impose and exception to this default behaviour seems to be the `RelativeLayout`. In that case, all what I just said became relative to the `RelativeLayout` except `Color` which continue being global. One can argue that Color is not a positioning instruction and [RelativeLayout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.relativelayout.html) is relative just to position. `Rotate` and `Translate` are position instructions but is it `Scale`?

I actually just finish a [blog post](http://robertour.com/?p=321) with an specific example

I am obviously missing something with the part of each Widget has its own `canvas`. So, basically my question is why does it seems that the widgets share the same canvas in Kivy?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I drove myself into a big mistake. This all started because the name `canvas` is confusing. I started to think that a canvas was a space in which we can draw. But not, the documentation is actually very clear here:

> Use this class to add graphics or context instructions that you want to be used for drawing [Kivy API - Canvas Class](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.Canvas))

And here:

> The canvas is a graphics object that contains all the drawing instructions for the graphical representation of the widget ([Kivy API - Canvas Property](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.widget.html?highlight=canvas#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.canvas)).

So, a canvas is a set of instructions (or sets if we think about `canvas.before` and `canvas.after`). **The instructions don't draw or are executed on a `canvas`, the instructions are just added to a `canvas`**. The instructions are executed in the **coordinate space**. For example, when there is a Rotate instruction in the canvas, it is going to be applied to any `VertexInstruction` (a `Line` for example) before being displayed in the **coordinate space**.

So, the widgets don't share a `canvas` but the instructions we add to the `canvas` share the same **coordinate space**.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, glad you figured it out. The name canvas seems to confuse a few people indeed. Your explanation is very clear and will probably help others. Maybe we should say something along these lines in the Programming Guide.

Comment: I was having a similar problem when I found this question. It helped me figure out that the canvas is not restricted to the widget space. In other words, the one widget can draw outside of its baudaries, in the whole application canvas.

Comment: That is right, except that there isn't actually a canvas in which you can draw. The canvas is a list of instructions that, when executed, draw in a coordinate space.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can read about canvas.before and canvas.after? I don't understand the differences but they seem to have different behaviour, especially with screen transitions.

Comment: There shouldn't be any differences except the order in which they are executed. When it comes to the point to draw a component, e.g. a Button, then the instructions in `canvas.before` are draw before  that the ones in `canvas`, which in turn are drawn before the ones in `canvas.after`. Importantly, (1) the instructions that draw the "default" Button are contained in `canvas`, and (2) any subcomponent (e.g. an `Image` inside the `Button`) is going to be drawn between `canvas` and `canvas.after` (and this rule is followed recursively).

Answer (score 2):

The other option is to use PushMatrix/PopMatrix to save/restore the context (translation/rotation) i think it's the most commonly used way in kivy.

Comment: That is useful but the names are not very intuitive.  I saw the classes and completely ignore them thinking they were not related. I still would like to understand how does it work internally. The canvas works more like a reference to something that is shared.

Comment: Indeed @tshirtman, I dug into `RelativeLayout`'s [code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/data/style.kv#L98). `RelativeLayout` does a `PushMatrix`, a `Translate` to `self.pos` and a `PopMatrix`. Which `Matrix` are we talking about? I am continue digging down. I resist to believe that `Matrix` is related to the resolution of the screen.

Comment: Got it now! We can "save" transformations in a small matrix that is "applied" to the objects that are being drawn. When I say applied I know there is very specific algebraic matrix operations. I remember I saw them in university but don't ask me which exactly.